# select2 4.0.0: How to change default language with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jquery-select2

I use RequireJS for importing javascript libraries. I wanted to change default language for select2 as guide in documentation, but no luck.

```
define(['jquery', 'select2'], function($) {
      $(".select2").select2({
           language: 'es'
      });
});
```

'select2' in define() is pointing *select2/dist/js/select2.full.js* in select2 4.0.0 package.

Do I have to manually load locale file *select2/dist/js/i18n/es.js* or do something else?

In addition, I'd like to change default language setting for all select2 instance, so that I don't need to pass language value there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87qf5dwd/7/) on how to set the default language, basically like this:
`$.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'jp');`

> The language does not have to be defined when Select2 is being
>   initialized, but instead can be defined in the [lang] attribute of any
>   parent elements as [lang="es"].

[Here is explained](https://select2.github.io/options.html#amd) how language files are loaded using require.js.

> How do I tell Select2 where to look for modules? For most AMD and
>   CommonJS setups, the location of the data files used by Select2 will
>   be automatically determined and handled without you needing to do
>   anything.
>
> If you are using Select2 in a build environment where preexisting
>   module names are changed during a build step, Select2 may not be able
>   to find optional dependencies or **language files**. You can manually set
>   the prefixes to use for these files using the amdBase and
>   amdLanugageBase options.
>
> 1. $.fn.select2.defaults.set('amdBase', 'select2/');
> 2. $.fn.select2.defaults.set('amdLanguageBase', 'select2/i18n/');

Here a list of supported languages:
[languages select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/master/src/js/select2/i18n)

Comment: I have a same problem .I use $.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'fa');  for persian language but does not work!!!!

Comment: It's working fine if you don't need to switch between languages automatically